# How do i disable a Jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This is my code below currently. I have tried this statement and many more on the last line of my code. How do i make the 'imagelbl' label disabled when i run this if statement.*

```
if(Cardgame.flip == 2){
        if(Cardgame.card.equals("aceace")){
            Cardgame.score = 1;
            String Text = Integer.toString(Cardgame.score);
            scorelbl.setText(Text);
            Cardgame.flip = 0;
            Cardgame.card = ("");
            //need to create a statement to disable the icon
            imagelbl.setEnable(false);
```

Comment: Do you mean even if the if-statement is not called? If so, which if statement?

Comment: Please a MVCE helps you a lot more than you think

Comment: what do you expect from a disabled label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  `myLabel.setEnabled(false)`
```

does only disabling the label, i.e. the label can no longer respond to user input. If you however want to hide the label you could try

```
  myLabel.setVisible(false)
```

should hide the icon.

Comment: If it's just "hide the icon", then the canonical way to do this is `myLabel.setIcon(null);`